# Easing effect for animating postion change

Tags: jquery, jquery-easing, easing-functions

I use this line of code for changing the position of an `ul` to get the requested `li` in focus.

```
$('ul#scroll').stop().animate({'left': new_pos+'px'},
    {duration: 50, easing: "swing"});
```

I tried some Effects like `smoothmove` but I get an error, that this effect can not be applied to my object.

`Linear` or `swing` are too boring.

Which effect can I use for animating the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use easing effects other than `swing` and `linear` you'd need to include jQueryUI.

> The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear.

http://api.jquery.com/animate

http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html